# HTML textarea box vanishes on command execution

Tags: html, css, perl

I have an application which is a combination of HTML front-end and PERL back-end. The back-end returns a certain message to the front-end element (a textarea box). But once the back-end sends the message to the front-end, the textbox vanishes. I think the textbox displays the message for a fleeting moment and then vanishes. How do I keep the textbox visible even after the command execution.

Code snippet:

```
if(returnedResult["rc"] == 10) {
        document.getElementById("outputArea").value = "returnedResult['message']";
        document.getElementById("outputTable").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("outputTableName").innerHTML = "Running Jobs";
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100%"><textarea id="outputArea" readonly=true style="height:100%;width:100%;"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

By cross checking with debug statements, I can guarentee that the codeflow enters the `if` condition. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Extra information as asked by Quentin:

```
<table id="outputTable" class="container" style="height:40%;width:50%;display:none" border=1 align="center">
     <tr>
         <td id = "outputTableName" style="width:100%;height:5%;">Calculating branch ...</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td style="width:100%"><textarea id="outputArea" readonly style="height:100%;width:100%;"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: There's no Perl in this question, only JavaScript. There's no sign of how the JS is triggered. There's no sign of how the Perl you haven't shared with us is triggered. There's no sign of `outputTable` or `outputTableName` in the HTML even though they are mentioned in the JavaScript. You need to provide a real [MCVE].

Comment: `readonly=true` — This is invalid HTML. The only value you can give to the `readonly` attribute is `readonly`. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)

Comment: @Quentin I put in the information for `outputTable` and `outputTableName`. The perl script is triggered on click on buttons that are present on the HTML page and a JS is called using `makeUserRequest2`. Along with the call other parameters including the PERL script path is also passed.

Comment: I also changed the table attribute from `readonly=true` to `readonly`

Comment: Don't just put bits of dissociated information in there. Provide a real [mcve]

Comment: does the "Calculating branch" row remain ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa no. The entire textarea disappears.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not really sure how I should organize the code in that manner. But with this amount of information what do you think? Is there any attribute which will allow me to keep the textarea visible even after `document.getElementById("outputTableName").innerHTML = "Running Jobs";` statement executes?

Comment: So you mean the entire `<table>` disappears, there is a `display: none;` property on your table. Are you sure you are not messing with that ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Yes, the entire `<table>` disappears and no that's not the case. The `display: none;` property ensures that when the web page is first opened, the textarea is invisible. Nevertheless, I tried running without that attribute but still didn't work

Comment: then can you check the web inspector for any console errors or display state of the table & let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125084/discussion-between-nikhil-hegde-and-nikhil-nanjappa).

Comment: It sounds like the problem is "You are submitting a form and that loads a new page", but none of the relevant code needed to determine that is in the question, so *shug*.

Answer (score -1):

You are using  innerHTML, that cause the issue. Basically innerHTML will remove the old html code and replace with your test "Running Jobs"

instead of this, please add another html tag with id and show the result with in it.

example:
in body
<span id="backenderrormessage"></span>

in java script:
document.getElementById("backenderrormessage").innerHTML = "Running Jobs";

Comment: `innerHTML` doesn't appear to be the issue. The element which is having a new value of `innerHTML` set is not an ancestor of the textarea.